# scanning a 2D char Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to scan a 2D char array in my C++ program. The problem is that my code does not scan the entire array as expected. For ex if I want it to scan a 41*41 array then for some reason it stops at 40th row and when I press enter it scans the one remaining row. Here is the simple piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
char G[101][101];
int N,M;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cin >> M >> N;
    cout << "m n scanned" << M << N << "\n";
for (int t =0;t<M;t++) {
    for (int j = 0;j<N;j++) {
        cin >> G[t][j];
        cout << "scanned " << t << " " << j << "\n";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

compiling: `testProj $g++ main.cpp -o main`

what am I missing here?

**Edit**: **input**
41 41
<2D char array of 41*41>

**Expected output**: 
scanned 40 40

**Actual Output** 
scanned 39 40
*press enter*

....

scanned 40 40

Comment: What inputs are you giving to the program, and what outputs are you getting vs. what you expect?

Comment: @JoeF edited the question with inputs and outputs.

Comment: You need to give an end sign to `cin`, like space or enter.

Comment: [It works for me](http://ideone.com/mKf4e9). Are you pressing enter key after last input. (41 * 41 char)?

Comment: @songyuanyao how can I do that ?

Comment: @shshnk I mean you do need to input a space or enter after inputting the last number.

Comment: @MohitJain works for me in the online ide too. https://ideone.com/VlgLFK . Not sure whats the problem when running it locally. No I am not pressing enter after 41*41 . I have to press it after 39*40. thats the issue.

Comment: You need to press it after all inputs. Unless you press enter, the input is not read.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me.

Input file, that gets piped to the executed code on standard input:

```
41 41
*****************************************
*****************************************

[ 39 more rows of the same ]
```

Output:

```
m n scanned4141
scanned 0 0
scanned 0 1
scanned 0 2

...

scanned 40 36
scanned 40 37
scanned 40 38
scanned 40 39
scanned 40 40
```

There's nothing wrong with the shown code, when used as is.

I suspect that you forgot a little detail that `operator>>` on `char` values is going to skip any whitespace, in addition to newline characters, and your input matrix contains spaces, which get ignored, and the code continues to look for 41*41 non-space characters to read. So, at this point, your code is waiting to read the expected amount of unread non-whitespace input.

Comment: when downvoting, please consider adding a comment ?